# What is this widget/element called in Android?

Tags: android

[image: This one?]

Many programs are using it, usually with long-click. Can I find it from Eclipse Android GUI editor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a context menu.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextMenu.html

"To show a context menu on long click, most clients will want to call registerForContextMenu(View) and override onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu, View, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo)."